# Polygon disapears after finishing edit in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, polygon-creation

I am working with ArcGIS Pro and I am editing some polygons for a project.

The problem I have is that after creating it and (!) finishing it with a double click it disappears. First, the polygon is filled with the color and the contour line and when I want to create a second one, it disappears. When I don't stop and create the second one still, the color is there for a second and disappears immediately.

I already watched a video on youtube for the creating part, and in the video, it does not happen like that, so I think it is a bug or such a thing but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: If you open your attribute table are the shapes there? You may have to ensure that the new layers can be symbolized (aka if categorical variables, that your new polygon with a new category is added to your symbology)

Comment: Make sure you don't have a definition query on that layer, otherwise the shapes will disappear after you create them because they will not match the query.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with some help! If you create Shapefiles make sure they are above the map in the Contents pane, if not, it will be underneath and then, like in my quest it will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue.

My problem was that the featureclass I was editing had a join attached, and new rows/features that were created did not have an entry in the join field.

Once I entered a key that corresponded with an appropriate from the join table, my polygon reappeared.