# Polygon disappearing after editing using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, editing, feature-class

I've created a polygon feature. When I go into "Edit" and then "Create Feature" however, I am unable to draw a polygon that gets saved to that feature. The polygon disappears as soon as I hit 'finish' and seems to get assigned to a line segment in a different place. I've checked to make sure I'm using the same coordinate systems across all my features/map so I don't think that is the problem. In the attribute table, there are shapes listed but they are all lines with Shape Area = 0. I've attached screenshots of the process below. I've created polygons so many times in ArcGIS, so I'm so confused why I can't do it in ArcGIS Pro. I've checked this similar post and it hasn't helped [Polygon disapears after finishing edit in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350645/polygon-disapears-after-finishing-edit-in-arcgis-pro).

What is going on here?

Step 1: Create polygon

[image]

Step 2: Hit "finish"

[image]

Step 3: Polygon disappears?!?!

[image]

Attribute Table

[image]

Comment: Seem obvious but have you check that you are not drawing a part of a multipolygon ,that you don't have any definition query or that your symbology didn't make your polygon invisible ?

Comment: There is no definition query, the symbology is set for everything to be a specific color and when I turn off all the other layers and basemaps, it's still not there. I'm not sure about the multipolygon part, but I set it up as a polygon feature class and am definitely not using the 'multiple polygons feature builder' tool in Arc.

Comment: Does the newly polygon appear in the attribute table ?, also what do you mean by "it seems to get assigned to a line segment in a different place"

Comment: A new shape appears in the attribute table that has a length, but not an area (which I believe indicates it is a line, even though it is marked as a polygon). Additionally, its difficult to see in the pics, but a bright blue line pops up above where I built the polygon when I hit finish. When I highlight it in the attribute table, I see it's the exact same line being built every time I create a new polygon.

Comment: One thing I just tried is to simply export to a new/fresh feature class. Does the issue still persist? It worked for me. I was having features disappear when I edited an attribute but a new new copy fixed the issue.